# Determinant of adjacency matrix of a graph

Tags: graph-theory

In a proof I found that
"Let G be a bipartite graph with odd n vertices. Since every bipartite graph has no odd cycles, it
follows that G has no elementary figure with n vertices. Then det(G) = 0."
How det(G) become zero..?

Answer (score 1):

This is due the following facts:

- A graph $G$ is bipartite if and only if it does not have an odd cycle.
- The determinant of a matrix is the sum of permutations as follows
  $$\text{det}(A)=\sum_{p}\sigma(p)a_{1p_1}a_{2p_2}...a_{np_n}.$$
  (here $p$ iterates over all permutations of $1$ to $n$, and $\sigma(p)$ is its parity.)
- Each such permutation of the adjacency matrix either includes a $0$, in which case it won't contribute to the determinant, or $a_{ip_i} = 1$ for all $1\leq i \leq n$. But that's also not possible, since each permutation corresponds to a partitioning of the vertices into a collection of cycles and isolated edges, and since the sum of their lengths is odd, one of them will have to be odd, which is impossible for a bipartite graph as per the first point.